# Parameterize resources.pipelines.pipeline.source value in ADO

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to parameterize the resources.pipelines.pipeline.source value in ADO?

```
pipelines:
    - pipeline: SSIS 
      project: 'ProjectName'
      source: TheProjectName_IspacBuild
```

The above works but if I change it to

```
pipelines:
    - pipeline: SSIS 
      project: 'ProjectName'
      source: $(TheProjectName)_IspacBuild
```

I get the following error:

**Pipeline Resource SSIS Input Must be Valid.**

I have tried using quotes'$(TheProjectName)_IspacBuild', "$(TheProjectName)_IspacBuild" and '"$(TheProjectName)_IspacBuild"' and all produce the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. It doesn't work with variables or runtime parameters. It has to be constant.

Comment: @lem could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?